# Java (Grails) or Erlang (Elixir) on short web-requests: speed, scalability?

Tags: java, erlang, webserver

I know that even a question Erlang or Java seems quite strange, because they are quite enough different languages with even different paradigms. But, now I know very superficially both of them, so, ask you what would you find more valuable to know, fast, **scalable**? What comes to my mind:

1. Java is mainstream language. I'm not sure about Groovy and Grails, but if project becomes more than your own hobby - it's much easier to find Java programmers to support this code. Elixir is a hobby of one good Erlang programmer - so it would be really difficult to support code in Elixir. Also, Grails is already written framework, so it should be better implemented that my own self-written in Elixir framework.
2. Erlang app (being well written) is the synonym of scalability. But when it comes to web apps that starts, do some lightweight queries and die - there's no need to scale them more than simple Round-Robin users queries between them (Java processes on different machines)?
3. If we are talking about many simple queries (no long-polling and etc.) - so many processes awake and die every second - Erlang has really lightweight process model, so .. What about Java and lots of new spawned and killed processed every second?

Thank you in advance.

PS [Chart](http://timyang.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/c_erlang_java_go.png) from [this](http://timyang.net/programming/c-erlang-java-performance/) performance test casts doubt on Java VM perfomance.

Comment: This is _probably_ a good fit for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). I've pinged their moderators to have a look. Your question will likely be migrated there in the near future. I'm leaving it open for now, however, even though it's a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. I think this could conceivably get some really good and interesting answers, but I want to double check with my colleagues before migrating.

Comment: Generally "what language/framework should I use?" questions are off topic for Programmers as they don't include any clear criteria for making the choice. This is *possibly* OK as it does have some criteria, but I'm not sure that the comparison you are trying to make is valid. I don't know enough to say one way or the other though.

Comment: @Minner: I don't think that benchmark has any validity.

Comment: Every language and framework is scalable and can (be made to) do the same, Erlang may just deliver some features "out of the box" that you would otherwise have to write yourself or import as a library. I agree with Josh K that the benchmark is far from any real-world scenario (it just serves a static string, so it only tests unoptimizable overhead but that's nothing you would be interested in to decide anything). More important: Choose what you are most familiar and comfortable with or get the most support for (help, libraries etc.). In business, hardware is often cheaper than wasted time.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Definitely, Java. The performance [test](http://timyang.net/programming/c-erlang-java-performance/)  you referenced shows that Java/Netty performance equals that of multicore Erlang, You can use numerous Java actor and async I/O libraries, so each request wouldn't start new process or thread - just create new handler in nanoseconds.

Comment: Well, the performance test uses the OTP web server and Erlang has many others servers available which are preferred by its community, like cowboy. Trusting that benchmark is like trusting the performance of Ruby web servers is the one given by webrick.

In any case, as others have said, I don't think this decision should be driven only by those benchmarks.